# Error al descargar archivos de NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

He estado intentando descargar System.Speech para reconocimiento de voz pero me da este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me puede ayudar?? Por que pasa eso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesitas agregar esta libreria desde `nuget` ya que deberia ser parte del `framework`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si la buscas agregando referencia deberia esta como opcion para agregar

Comment: ohhhh muchas gracias.... el problema es q en la version 2017 del vs no me salia pero al parecer como esta la descargue online lo descargo muchas gracias